# Accessing DLNA UPnP server

Tags: winapi, upnp, dlna

The idea is to download any available media file from a DLNA server into my sequencer for processing, or even allowing a transcode through a Media Foundation interface.

After some testing I created`IUPnPDeviceFinderCallback`, using it in an instantiated `IUPnPDeviceFinder`, searching for "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1".

I'm not sure if this string is always valid, is there a list of valid URIs ?  In my system it succeeds in finding the Serviio DLNA server.

Now using the `IUPnPDevice::get_Services` I get an enumerator that enumerates the `IUPnPService`. But I'm not sure on how to proceed from now on, the documemtation seems very sparse. Now what?  Some media-server specific invoke to be passed  to `IUPnPService::InvokeAction`? What would that be?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: mediaserver specific calls yes, [ContentDirectory](http://www.upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-ContentDirectory-v4-Service.pdf) service to be even more specific. I'd suggest looking for a DLNA / UPnP-AV library: implementing this yourself is going to be a lot of work and if you want your implementation to actually work with more than one mediaserver you'll need a vast amount of interoperability  testing.

Comment: You can use this open source tool https://github.com/nccgroup/UPnP-Pentest-Toolkit at least to discover your devices and their capabilities.